# Trigger Binding to Child Control Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have this on a WPF Window

```
<local:TestControl>
    <local:TestHost />
</local:MediaPlayer>
```

Classes defined like this

```
public class TestControl : ContentControl
{
    static TestControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestControl)));
        ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ContentChanged, CoerceContent));
    }

    private static void ContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var P = d as TestControl;
        P.Host = e.NewValue as TestHost;
    }

    private static object CoerceContent(DependencyObject d, object baseValue) => baseValue as TestHost;

    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HostProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Host", typeof(TestHost), typeof(TestControl), null);
    public TestHost Host { get => (TestHost)GetValue(HostProperty.DependencyProperty); protected set => SetValue(HostProperty, value); }
}

public class TestHost : Control
{
    static TestHost()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestHost), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestHost)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPlaying", typeof(bool), typeof(TestHost), 
        new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool IsPlaying { get => (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty); set => SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value); }
}
```

Then in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="False" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Host.IsPlaying, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyButton" Property="Content" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It should display "true" in the button, but remains "false".

Setting a breakpoint when setting Host, it does get called and Host does get set correctly.

I'm getting this in the debug log after changing VS option to display all binding debug info.

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'Host' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Host.IsPlaying; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Note that creating a normal binding outside the trigger does work

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="{Binding Host.IsPlaying, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

How can I get this trigger binding to work?

Comment: This appears to be essentially [the exact same question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451179/why-is-wpf-trigger-not-being-called). You should not delete and repost questions as a way to try to "bump" or otherwise increase visibility of your question. Consider what this site would look like if everyone did that. Instead, make sure you've improved your question, and wait for an answer.

Comment: In a Trigger in a ControlTemplate, you give it the name of a property of the control you're templating. In a DataTrigger in a ControlTemplate, use `{RelativeSource Self}`. When you stop thinking and tell yourself a "bug in the framework" story, you prevent yourself from learning. Your readonly dependency property definition is also a bit strange, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: What's with the negative attitude? Anyway, now it's working, thanks.

Comment: @EtienneCharland "Negative attitude?" I don't follow.

Comment: btw there IS a bug. When setting {RelativeSource Self], intellisense isn't working, and the Binding Editor is instead showing properties of the trigger itself. MS just added this to fix in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Well... here's "one" way

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="False" Height="50" Width="100" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="IsPlayingHidden" Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding Host.IsPlaying, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="IsPlayingHidden" Property="Text" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyButton" Property="Content" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This works, but it's ugly.

It really looks like a bug in the framework.